# nsis disable next button of component page

Tags: button, nsis

I am writing a installer using nsis.
On ".onInit" Iam checking prerequisite software are there or not and based on that I want to enable or disable "Next" button of component page.Here is what iam trying

```
Function .onInit
     ${If} $JavaExists == false ;check if java is installed
          ${OrIf} $TomcatExists == false ;check if tomcat is installed
               ${OrIf} $MysqlExists == false ;check if mysql is installed
               ;code to disable next button of component page
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component page does not exist in .oninit, you need to call `GetDlgItem`+`EnableWindow` in the show callback for the component page...

Comment: Thanks for your reply but which is that method.I could not find callback method for show

Comment: will !define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW help ?

Comment: Yes if you are using MUI, if not its page components "" myshow

Answer (score 0):

this code may help you

```
${NSD_CreateButton} 40% 150 80 14u "Next"
Pop $BUTTON
EnableWindow $BUTTON 0--------;; disables button
```